# Need to insert row in table if primary keys do not exist, otherwise update existing row

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to run a bunch of SQL that will check if a composite primary key value exists in the table.  if it exists, then update the table, otherwise insert new values.  I thought a merge statement was the way to do this.  But the merge I have written gets 0 rows merged when I run it.  I would expect the NOT MATCHED condition to occur in the following example, but it does not. Here is the script to test it and the MERGE I am trying:

```
CREATE TABLE curformat (storeent_id INTEGER,
                        setccurr VARCHAR2(3),
                        roundingmultiple INTEGER,
                        numbrusg_id INTEGER,
                        roundingmethod VARCHAR2(1),
                        decimalplaces INTEGER,
                        MINAPPROVEAMOUNT NUMBER,
                        optcounter INTEGER);

INSERT INTO curformat VALUES(-1, 'USD', 1, -1, 'R', 2, NULL, NULL);

----------------------------------------------------------------------

MERGE INTO curformat cf
USING (SELECT *
         FROM curformat
        WHERE storeent_id = 10201
          AND setccurr = 'USD'
          AND numbrusg_id = -1
      ) current_curformat
      ON (cf.storeent_id = current_curformat.storeent_id
          AND cf.setccurr = current_curformat.setccurr
          AND cf.numbrusg_id = current_curformat.numbrusg_id
         )
 WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
      SET roundingmultiple = 1,
          roundingmethod = 'R',
          decimalplaces = 2,
          minapproveamount = NULL
 WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (storeent_id, setccurr, roundingmultiple, numbrusg_id, roundingmethod, decimalplaces, minapproveamount)
      VALUES (10201, 'USD', 1, -1, 'R', 2, NULL
             );
```

In this case, since the combination of

```
WHERE storeent_id = 10201
AND setccurr = 'USD'
AND numbrusg_id = -1
```

is not true, I would have thought the WHEN NOT MATCHED would be run. 
Can anyone help me understand what I am not understanding here?  I imagine I am mis-using the MERGE statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sstan has already explained why your version of MERGE will not work. When you want to update / insert into `curformat`, you don't pull rows from that table. You have "new" rows that you either want to insert into your table or you want to use for update.

So - it is actually easy to fix your MERGE statement. Pay close attention to what the "delta" is though (`current_format` used in the USING clause). In this case, it is a row created from "thin air" (which in Oracle means "created from the `dual` table").

```
MERGE INTO curformat cf
USING (SELECT 10201 as storeent_id,
              'USD' as setccurr,
              -1    as numbrusg_id
       FROM   dual
      ) current_curformat
      ON (cf.storeent_id = current_curformat.storeent_id
          AND cf.setccurr = current_curformat.setccurr
          AND cf.numbrusg_id = current_curformat.numbrusg_id
         )
 WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
      SET roundingmultiple = 1,
          roundingmethod = 'R',
          decimalplaces = 2,
          minapproveamount = NULL
 WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (storeent_id, setccurr, roundingmultiple, numbrusg_id,
                                     roundingmethod, decimalplaces, minapproveamount)
      VALUES (10201, 'USD', 1, -1, 'R', 2, NULL
             );
```

This will do exactly what you want.

However, here we hardcoded the values to be inserted when there is no match. That is a very poor practice. The correct way to do this is (just showing the last two rows, which are the only ones changed):

```
      VALUES (current_format.storeent_id, current_format.setccurr,
                                 1, current_format.numbrusg_id, 'R', 2, NULL
             );
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are looking at this backwards. If we take the basic `merge` syntax:

```
merge into <target> using <source> ...
```

... the idea is that you have a set of rows defined as the `source` that may or may not match some rows in your `target`, and for which you define the logic on how to merge the `source` into the `target`.  But in order for the `merge` statement to perform any work at all, `source` can't be empty.

In your case, the `source` is defined as:

```
SELECT *
  FROM curformat
 WHERE storeent_id = 10201
   AND setccurr = 'USD'
   AND numbrusg_id = -1
```

...which returns no rows, so there is nothing to do. `target` can be empty though, but if `source` is empty, there is nothing to merge into `target`.